# App crashes on iPad but works well on iPhone4 and iPod touch

Tags: ios, ipad

And the problem is in the code:

```
self.remindItem = [[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"提醒" 
                                   image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"remind.png"] tag:0] autorelease];
[self.remindItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"remind_tapped.png"] 
         withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"remind.png"]];
self.remindItem.badgeValue = @"2";
```

whenever I try to run it on my iPad (1st generation,ios4.2.1)

it crashes and says:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x164100'

but it really works well on other devices,

is there any problems about my code? other XCode?

Comment: What ios are you running on your other devices?  ios 4.2.1 might not have the api you are calling (indeed that is what it looks like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> Available in iOS 5.0 and later.

setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage: was added in iOS 5.0, which is why it won't work on your iPad.

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening due to possible **Memory Leaking**.In many cases,when iPad is out of memory it calls view did Unload of some View Controllers.